# JavaScript function returning undefined. Looping through nodelist of buttons for click event

Tags: javascript, function, dom, events, undefined

While trying to adapt my console.log Rock Paper Scissors game to use a GUI - I've setup buttons for the user input but the function I've put together keeps returning undefined (getPlayerSelection).

Specifically I'm trying to return the text content of the button clicked so that I can use that as the user's input. The console.log(input) shows the correct string but when I try to return that value it always shows as undefined.

HTML

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Rock Paper Scissors!</title>
</head>
<body>

    <section id="choices">
    <button class="button">Rock!</button>
    <button class="button">Paper!</button>
    <button class="button">Scissors!</button>
    </section>

    <script src="javascript.js" defer></script>
</body>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
    // player input

function getPlayerSelection(){

        const buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('button');

        let input = '';
            
        for (const btn of buttons) {
            btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
                input =  btn.textContent;
                console.log(input);
            })
        }

        return input;
    
    }


    // computer input

function getComputerChoice(){
        let randomChoice = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
            
        if(randomChoice === 0){
            return("Rock!")
        } else if(randomChoice === 1){
            return("Paper!")
        } else {
            return("Scissors!")
        }
    }


function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection) {

    playerSelection = getPlayerSelection();
    computerSelection = getComputerChoice();
```

I've tried setting up individual class names for each button and having their own event listeners but I think I must be misunderstanding how DOM manipulation works. This also returns undefined.

```
    const rockBtn = document.querySelector('.rockButton');
    rockBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
        return 'Rock!';
    });

    const paperBtn = document.querySelector('.paperButton');
    paperBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
        return 'Paper!';
    });

    const scissorsBtn = document.querySelector('.scissorsButton');
    scissorsBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
        return 'Scissors!';
    });
```

Comment: returning from a handler attached with addEventListener has no effect (where would you expect to see the returned value?). As for `getPlayerSelection()` you aren't specifying a return at all and functions without an explicit return always return undefined. The function *is* attaching listeners to each button though, so clicking them should log as expected.

Comment: While it's not an error, it's unusual to use parentheses when returning data from a function. IOW, just use `return "Rock!";` as opposed to `return("Rock!")`. Also, be careful to use `var` (or better yet, `const`) when defining variables (i.e,, `const input  = btn.textContent;` vs `input = btn.textContent;`).

Comment: Thank you both for responding. I just updated the js above with my earlier attempt - do you know how I could assign the textContent to a variable outside of the loop, so that the function could then return it?

Comment: You can use event.target to get the selected button. Loop over the buttons and add a "click" event listener to pass the event into the callback function. Perhaps adding a unique ID to the options will allow you to select that id using something like **e.target.id**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that your higher order function, **playGround**, was not structured well and you tried returning the text content of the buttons before hooking into them via the DOM API.

There was no error logged because you initialized the input variable with an empty string and thus an empty string was all that was returned.

To cut the long story short, whenever you called the **playGround** function, the empty input variable was returned, you called the function before linking the buttons in your code.

The following code should work, you can tweak it as you see fit

HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Rock Paper Scissors!</title>
    <script src="javascript.js" defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <section id="choices">
      <button class="button">Rock!</button>
      <button class="button">Paper!</button>
      <button class="button">Scissors!</button>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

JS

```js
const buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("button");
for (const btn of buttons) {
  btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    playRound(btn.textContent);
  });
}

function getPlayerSelection(input) {
  return input;
}

function getComputerChoice() {
  let randomChoice = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);

  if (randomChoice === 0) {
    return "Rock!";
  } else if (randomChoice === 1) {
    return "Paper!";
  } else {
    return "Scissors!";
  }
}

function playRound(playerSelection) {
  playerSelection = getPlayerSelection(playerSelection);
  computerSelection = getComputerChoice();
  console.log(`Player: ${playerSelection}`, `Computer: ${computerSelection}`);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Chisom! This worked, I'm going to review all the DOM manipulation content through TOP because I don't think I've fully got my head wrapped around it yet. Really appreciate it.